# Is Chrome function gc() synchronous?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm starting Chrome 64.0.3282.140 with `--expose-gc` flag making use of the `gc()` function. I'm just wondering: Is this function synchronous?

In order words: Can I be sure that in a code like

```
var memoryBeforeGC = window.performance.memory;
gc();
var memoryAfterGC = window.performance.memory;
```

`gc();` has finished when `memoryAfterGC` is assigned?
If not: What can I do? How long shall I wait via timeout?